# Open menù on fullscreen app

Tags: macos, display, fullscreen

I'm using this arrangement for my notebook + 24inch monitor.
I primarily work on my notebook and the big screen is used just for secondary stuff.

The problem is that i cannot use full-screen application on the lower screen because there is no way to open the menù. Usually you have to put your mouse on the top of the screen, but in this arrangement when you move the mouse to the top, it simply jumps to the other screen.

Any advices?

[image: screen arrangement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use keyboard shortcut to get focus on menubar with <kbd>⌃ CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. This will show menubar also in fullscreen apps.

Note: when You use Your <kbd>F2</kbd> key for brightness control, You need to add <kbd>fn</kbd> to this shortcut to work properly.